# Database can be accessed by all

Tags: oracle

I have installed Oracle 10g Lite on an administrative system with 32-bit Windows XP as the OS. I have N client systems with a mix of 32/64-bit Windows 7/8 OSes.

How can I configure the server as well as the clients so that the database can be accessed by all? With it we have a wireless router, IB-WRX300-N , providing the internet to all.

Comment: different users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270649/database-accessed-by-clients

Comment: Different user, but on topic here.

Comment: Hello Ishaan, what configuration are you talking about exactly? If you're talking about networking/DNS/firewall and such, you're not in the best place for that and your question lacks specifics. If you're talking about something else, then please try and explain that in more detail.

Comment: I am a little bit uneasy about the idea of installing a production database on a non server operating system that will no longer be supported by Microsoft soon and using wireless for transmitting the data.  There are just so many ways this can go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you say Oracle 10g Lite I assume you mean Express Edition.  I recommend you read through the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/xe102/homepage), particularly the section on [Connecting to the Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/connecting.htm#CEGIFAHF).  If you have a more specific question after reading that, we would be glad to help.